# Liquibase with Maven misses class when working with YAML-changelog

Tags: yaml, maven-3, liquibase, snakeyaml, changelog

I added the following dependency into my Maven pom-file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

My liquibase.properties looks like this:

```
driver:oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
classpath: PUB/common/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0-atlassian-hosted.jar;PUB/common/lib/snakeyaml-1.12.jar
url:jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=XXXX)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX.dev)))
username:user
password:password
changeLogFile: src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.yaml
```

but everytime I use the update goal with Maven, I get this message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:update (Liquibase1) on project some-important-project: Execution Liquibase1 of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:update failed: A required class was missing while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:update: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml
```

I couldn't find anything on Google, and the Liquibase documentation is extremely bad.

What am I making wrong here?

Comment: where did you add that dependency? Can you share do code?

Comment: I added the dependency into the pom file where all the other dependencies regarding liquibase are.

Comment: you maybe need to add that dependency to plugin

Comment: it is downloading the snakeyaml.jar and puts it in the folder where all other jar-files are stored, but it doesn't use it I think

Comment: I had the same issue, i resolved it by upgrading the version of liquibase-maven-plugin